# count dupplicated data on json file using java

Tags: java, json, list, bufferedreader

am trying to count all the duplicate data from a json file, but i dont get the right count of the data, im thinking to arrange the data before i add it to a list but its possible to arrange json data? what i think for the ouput :

```
component : pensil : 5 
               pen : 1
```

here is my codes. some tips guys thanks.

```
public Main1(){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String inputline,aa;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/lyod/Documents/sample.json"));
        try {
            String id = null,component = null,title = null,lat = null,
            lng = null, cost = null, status = null;
            while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(inputline);
                for (Object o : a) {
                    JSONObject sample = (JSONObject) o;
                    id = (String) sample.get("id");
                    component = (String) sample.get("component");
                    list.add(component);
                    aa =(component+" " + Collections.frequency(list, component));
                }
                System.out.println(aa);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your input file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you could use a [HashBag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/bag/mutable/HashBag.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), a [HashBag](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html) from Apache Commons Collections or a [HashMultiset](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html) from Guava.

You can add your items to a `Bag`/`Multiset` like any other collection, and internally they will keep track of the count for you.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

I would go like this:

1. Create `HashMap<String, Integer>`, let key be component and value be number of occurences.
2. Go thru the json file with `while` as you do. For every component check the presence in hash map - if it is present, increase value by 1, if not present, put new value 1 under the key of component.
3. Print in cycle all keys (components) and values (count of duplicates).

You are done.

Comment: than you @martin ill try.